# for loop in for loop without initialization

Tags: c

Here is my C code which I compiled and executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned i = 0, j = 0;
    unsigned s = 0;

    for (; i <= 1; i++)
        for (; j <= 1; j++)
            s++;

    printf("%u\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to see 4, but I saw 2.
I can not understand why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `i` loop, `j` starts at 0, and ends at 2. The second `i` iteration, `j` is still 2, so you don't execute the `j` loop.

Answer (score 10):

It's in your title: you don't initialize `j` in the inner for.

So the sequence will be: (i,j):

```
0,0
0,1
0,2 (inner for won't enter body)
1,2 (inner for won't enter body)
2,2 (outer for won't enter body)
```

In situations like this, you should write on paper step by step each variable value and check every test. The next step is to learn how to **use the debugger**. It's immensely helpful and will spare you a lot of headaches. I can't emphasize enough how much easier your life will be made by a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here

```
firstly i=0;
then inner loop executes 2 times
for j=0 and j=1
now j becomes 2 and inner loop terminates
outer loop executes now for i = 1
but your inner loop has no initialisation so j would remain 2 and as a result inner loop never executs now aftet being executed for i=0
```

So solution is change inner loop as

```
for( j=0;j<=1;j++);
```

it will work now.
Gud luck

Answer (score 0):

if you don't initialize j for the second time around your program wont execute the inner for-loop body.

and a tip - be explicit about your code. not only for the compiler to "understand" what you want but also for other programmers reading your code.
in this code it is fairly obvious that

```
unsigned i
```

actually means

```
unsigned int i
```

but in another, bigger more complicated code it wont be so easy to guess.

Comment: I have never encountered or hear about a problem or even an ambiguity caused by writing `unsigned` instead of `unsigned int`. Never heard about anyone complaining about this.

Comment: there is no ambiguity when it comes to the compiler. just a suggestion to make his code more readable. an understandable code is one understood by a reader with little or no codding knowledge. just saying...

Comment: I know what you meant, and when I mentioned ambiguity I was referring to humans interpreting the code. And anyone who wrote more than 5 programs in C knows that `unsigned` without a basic data type means `unsigned int`. Anyway, it's just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;
   unsigned int s = 0;

    for (; i <= 3; i++) //its supose to be 3 not 1 since its not going to add up to 4. 

    for (; j <= 3; j++)
        s++;

printf("%u\n", s);
getch();
return 0;
```

}

> The problem was in the loops n_n !